# on-down not workig. Alternative?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm using Polymer to fire an event but it doesn't work the right way on mobile:

```
<paper-button  data-key="LEFT" on-down="handleButton">
    <iron-icon data-key="LEFT" icon="hardware:keyboard-arrow-left" style="color: white;"></iron-icon>
</paper-button>
```

on-down fires the handleButton. But once fired it never stops executing the action. on-tap does also not work. How can i only execute the "handleButton" as long as the user keeps pressing the button down?

We're using PubNub to transmitt data between devices. This handles the button:

```
handleButton: function(e){
    this.$.pub.message = {"type":"button", "data":e.currentTarget.dataset.key.toString()};
    this.$.pub.publish();
},
```

Comment: Can you show your handleButton function

Comment: @MojtabaSafaeian i've added the function. If you're up to a minimal short term paid job i can also send you the whole JS and html.